# Linebreak issue with Beanstalk Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Node.js app running in Elastic Beanstalk and logging using console.log, console.error etc...then I have CloudWatch logs turned on. When I go to the Insights and do a query it shows up but somehow it is logging line by line instead of the entire error.

In the example screenshot I want the entire log from a single console.log to go to a single log record...so one to one, instead of splitting by new lines...is there a way to do this without removing all line breaks during console.log? Say a configuration option or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output of the application is sent to standard out (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`). The AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment leverages Linux rsyslog to capture `stdout` and `stderr` to write the information into log files.

This is done through standard rsyslog configuration found here: /etc/rsyslog.d/web.conf

```
if $programname  == 'web' then {
    *.=warning;*.=err;*.=crit;*.=alert;*.=emerg /var/log/web.stderr.log
    *.=info;*.=notice /var/log/web.stdout.log   
}
```

It is rsyslog that interprets the stack trace from `stdout` as multiple entries and writes multiple lines in AWS CloudWatch Logs.

I wrote a [small article on GitHub](https://github.com/jblaplace/aws-beanstalk-java-exceptions-one-line) that describe the solution for a Java environment but you can do something similar for Node.JS.